# loosing full-screen when changing pages or refreshing

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

In my web application I have a button to allow the users to work on full-screen mode. My problem is that it's only working for the current page, if we click a link or in any other way change pages or even if we refresh the current one the full-screen mode is lost.

this is the function I'm using to allow the full-screen:

```
// Handle full screen mode toggle
var handleFullScreenMode = function () {
  // toggle full screen
  function toggleFullScreen() {
    if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {  // current working methods
      if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
        document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
      }
    } else {
      if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
        document.cancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
      }
    }
  }

  $('#trigger_fullscreen').click(function () {
    toggleFullScreen();
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  handleFullScreenMode();
});
```

Is there anyway to keep the it when changing pages like what happens when you click F11?

Comment: So the page itself refreshes? Its not doing js and staying in the view?

Comment: You can keep the state of full-screen mode through page reloads by storing it's value in cookies or localStorage/sessionStorage and reapplying your full-screen function depending on that.

Comment: @hindmost that would work to a certain level, but I prefer to remove the full-screen functionality than to have the window changing sizes all the time. It gets a bit frustrating and frustration is not something i want the users to feel when using my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

The [API specifies](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/) that fullscreen will only operate on the current, or descending browser contexts.

When the page is changed or refreshed, the browser context changes, and the fullscreen effect is lost.

[MDN also reinforces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode) with:

> ... navigating to another page, changing tabs, or switching to another application (using, for example, Alt-Tab) while in fullscreen mode exits fullscreen mode as well.